# "One step" like or direct shortcuts/gestures for Windows 8 touch devices as for keyboard/android devices?

Tags: note-taking, windows

Similar to [this question](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/3444/560) I'm trying to increase productivity on Windows 8 Tablet with touchscreen. Coming from PC/Notebook where I use extensively [Autohotkey shortcuts](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/q/677/560) I need more gesture like command or shortcut buttons on a Tablet with touchscreen. The [standard windows 8 gestures](http://liliputing.com/2012/03/list-of-windows-8-touch-based-gestures.html) are nice but for things like my:

- favorite software (dictionary, music player, ...)
- certain shortcut combos (paste, copy,...)
- fast switching between apps (Alt+Tab)

I would like to have small touchbuttons on the side or top of the screen wich I simply touch and then this shortcut/command is executed or make a special gesture on the middle of the screen (for instance draw a circle or a S) and then it gets executed.

For Android you find [lots of competing apps that can do this](http://www.ipagereviewlists.com/faster-app-switching-10-must-apps-android/) (especially PieControl and SwipePad are very nice here), for windows there are much less apps, but even such basic stuff I cannot find.

Can anybody recommend such apps or how to do this in Windows 8 with a touchdevice without keyboard? The standard tools from windows 8 to open often a sidebar and then click that recent app is to indirect and two step like, I want like with keyboard shortcuts or android apps a one step gesture or button like command on windows 8.